# Create a JSON Object using java

Tags: java, json

I am new to `JSON creations` . I want to create a  JSON object for each element in the for-each loop. My code is like

```
for(int i=0 ; i<=childclasses.size() ;i++ ){

                for (OInstance oinstance:oinstances){

                    oinstancelist.add(oinstance);

                 }

                }

            try {

                object.put("subclass",oclass);
                object.put("instance", oinstancelist);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("json is  " +object);
```

I want to create a json object for every oinstance . So,How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

With [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), creating a JSON-String is as easy as:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(oinstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

GSON is good and always faster then JSON.

However for JSON, Get json-simple-1.1.1.jar and add into your classpath and write below logic to create JSON object

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
class JsonEncodeDemo {
      public static void main(String[] args){
      JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
      obj.put("name", "jsonObject");
      obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
      obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
      obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));
      System.out.print(obj);
   }
}
```

You will get output like : {"balance": 1000.21, "num":100, "is_vip":true, "name":"jsonObject"}

However, as you are new to JSON you can visit [this](http://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json) also.